# How to use StubToolkit instead of Quantum toolkit for my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, jar, jenkins, javafx, classnotfoundexception

I would like to run TestFX tests for JavaFX on a headless Jenkins. One way to do this is to use "StubToolkit" instead of QuantumToolkit as using the latter in headless mode gives me a "java.awt.AWTException: headless environment" exception. StubToolkit is described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg04381.html).

In order to test the procedure, I'd like to first run a regular JavaFX application with the StubToolkit. So I...

1. built OpenJFX (8),
2. ran the tests using `gradle test`,
3. located the StubToolkit class files under `modules/graphics/build/classes/test/com/sun/javafx/pgstub/`,
4. put them into a jar using java `jar cf StubToolkit.jar com` (from the `modules/graphics/build/classes/test` directory),
5. copied the jar next to my sample JavaFX application (`MyApp.java`), and
6. ran the app using `java -cp "StubToolkit.jar;." -Djavafx.toolkit=com.sun.javafx.pgstub.StubToolkit MyApp`

This gave me a CNFE:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.pgstub.StubToolkit
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:213)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:637)
...
```

My JavaFX application looks like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.sun.javafx.pgstub.StubPerformanceTracker;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Label label = new Label("Hello World.");
            Scene scene = new Scene(label, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            System.out.println(new StubPerformanceTracker());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I included the System.out call to check if the classes from the StubToolkit jar are correctly put on the classpath, and my application indeed runs without any problems when I start it without the `-D` switch using `java -cp "StubToolkit.jar;." MyApp`.

I ran all these tests on a 64bit Windows 7.

Any ideas what's wrong? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! Makes the problem a lot clearer than via Twitter :-) I'm curious what happens if you manually try to load the StubToolkit class in your application.

Class.forName("com.sun.javafx.pgstub.StubToolkit").newInstance();

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/2872be3a2984/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/tk/Toolkit.java

Comment: So, we confirmed that the class is present and loadable, so it must be a classloader issue then; the classloader being used does not "see" the class. That will require some reading in the classloader logic I figure.

Comment: It seems to be working in your setup, so the question is what the relevant differences are between my environment and yours. Could you comment on that? And do you think this would be worth bringing up on the openjfx-dev mailing list?

Comment: How do you mean "working in your setup"? I have no such code up and running.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you had been more lucky with this than I was.

Comment: Thanks to [this answer](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2014-January/012481.html) on the JFX mailing list, I got one step further: I do not see the CNFE anymore, but the code still does not run as expected. I get no output at all and the application never finishes. I set a breakpoint in my main method but it was never reached.